# Magento 2 - Transactional email templates

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2, email, custom-variable

How I can get Sales Representative Contact Email in a transactional email templates?

I try to add something like this but the href is not display:

```
<li style="background: black; color:white;">

    {{trans
        "If you have any questions please feel free to contact us at ' <a href="{{config path="trans_email/ident_sales/email"}}">{{config path="trans_email/ident_sales/email"}}</a> ', by phone."
}}
</li>
```

Maybe is something wrong in my code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your code with the below snippet.

```
<li style="background: black; color:white;">    
   If you have any questions please feel free to contact us at
   <a href={{ trans config path='trans_email/ident_sales/email'}}>
   {{config path=trans_email/ident_sales/email}}</a> , by phone.
</li>
```

Comment: @Robert Does this works for you

Comment: Hi, thanks but where is {{trans? or for what you removed?

Comment: I have removed {{ trans}} and placed it in the href and link portion. We need {{trans}}  syntax only when we use any dynamic variables inside our text. For plain text there is no need to use trans. Kindly accept the answer if your problem is resolved.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your answer and for your help.

Comment: How can you pull the sales representative's name? I tried this {{ trans config path='trans_email/ident_sales/name'}} but it didn't work. @mydons